# How to relaunch a Windows 10 IoT app programmatically

Tags: c#, uwp, iot, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

I have a Windows 10 IoT app developed in C#, and I need to relaunch the app when the configuration has changed. How can the app relaunch itself programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Base on the [Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4126436/richard)'s comments I have resolved as follows:

1. I set my application as the default application (see picture)
2. When I need to relaunch the app, simply close it and the operating system opens again.

**Setting the default app**
[image: How to set the default app]

**The code for close the app is:**

```
private void Exit()
{
   Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.Exit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using powershell right after a configuration deployment to restart it?
https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PowerShell.htm

the command

> net start 'program'

should be what you're looking for in powershell

For the Device:
Since IoT only allows 1 app at a time, have you considered just issuing the device itself a the restart command and the application to go on startup

Comment: I need the application itself automatically relauch, but your solution is for I relaunch from the pc.

Comment: Just to clarify on the question before I edit the answer, you need to restart the app when the configuration has changed due to user input on the device?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The app must to restart when the configuration has changed due to user input on the device.

Comment: Since IoT only allows 1 app, have you considered just issuing the device itself a the restart command and the application to just go on startup?

Comment: I've edited this answer to include your specific circumstance (for future readers).  Happy coding!